# Selenium scripts don't run on open brower

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium with java on Ubuntu.  I am trying to run selenium code on a browser that is already open.  I have found a few solutions but they all crash for me.  I can open the browser and run my code normally if I don't do any of the following.

I include `options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");` because I need to add it when I launch a browser.

Here is what I have tried and the results.

In the terminal I type
`google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9988`
The browser is launched.  In another terminal I type
`sudo netstat -tulpn |grep :9988`.  I get a result of
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9988          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      47330/chrome --remo` .  This should mean my port is good.

When I type http://127.0.0.1:9988 into a new browser nothing happens.   From what I have read it should duplicate the debugger window.

I run the following code but always crashes when I instantiate the browser.  I have tried every combination of the options.

```
private void ports() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");     
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
//      options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9988");

        options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9988");
//      options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9988");

        WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver(options);      
        browser.get("https://www.bbccom/");

    }
```

It crashes with the following output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 119.0.6045.105 (38c72552c5e15ba9b3117c0967a0fd105072d7c6-refs/branch-heads/6045@{#1103}) on port 46485
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:9989
from chrome not reachable
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'clay-HP-ENVY-17-Notebook-PC', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2.0-36-generic', java.version: '17.0.8.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], debuggerAddress: localhost:9989, extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], debuggerAddress: localhost:9989, extensions: []}}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:264)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:179)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:70)
    at top.OpenBrowser.ports(OpenBrowser.java:131)
    at top.OpenBrowser.run(OpenBrowser.java:31)
    at top.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

These are the places I have tried:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rrkj4tdXngY

Another https://cosmocode.io/how-to-connect-selenium-to-an-existing-browser-that-was-opened-manually/#launch-browser-with-custom-flags

Comment: My version of selenium was not the most recent.  That was the problem.